# Why MMA is not able to solve this problem?

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, warning-messages

I am running these following code in Mathematica. But, MMA does not output anything. It is giving me an message as "The integrand .... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the \
region with boundaries {{[Infinity],1.}}".

$$\mathcal{L}_{I_{\text{M}}}[s]=\exp\left(-\pi p_b\lambda_{\text{M}}\mathbb{E}_H\left(\int_r^\infty\left(1-\exp\left(-sP_{\text{M}}Hr^{-1/\delta}\right)\right){\rm{d}}r\right)\right)$$

Note that when I put $K=0$, it works fine and gives me the expected result. But, for other values of $K$, It gives me the error.

Comment: Your `LI` which is equal to your `M` and then your `B` is not a number.... When your code doesn't run you should try to track back and find where the error is occuring.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, Yes, it is true. $B$ is a function of $r$. Note that this MMA code works fine for $K=0$.

Comment: In this case `Expectation[int, 
 h \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[f[h], {h, 0, Infinity}]]` is not returning a numerical value. (Even if it has a numerical `r`).

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, is there anything that I can do?

Comment: It's hard to say what the best route forward is without knowing exactly what you are trying to do and what flexibility you require in your solution.

Comment: Can you break your problem down and achieve intermediate steps? For example, what is the desired behaviour of `LI`? Is it a variable or a function? You'll likely have to attack the implementation of `LI` numerically with either `NExpectation` or just use `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, Thanks for your comment. Please see the edited question with more informations. Please suggest me a way to calculate it.

Comment: What does your integrand in `AverageProbSuccess` evaluate to at, say, `r == 10.`?

Comment: `@MichaelE2, How $r$ is connected to this error? Any, at this moment I cannot use MMA. But as I mentioned that when I set $K=0$, I get expected result. But when I use a higher $K$, it fails to give me the output.  The value for AverageProbSuccess is between 0 and 1.

Comment: I'm suggesting that a basic trouble-shooting strategy is to see how the integrand behaves when you plug in specific values of `r`.  At least for the code posted, I don't get an expression that can be integrated.  Try it, when you get the chance.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Expectation` does not evaluate to a numeric result in all cases.  It's also quite slow.  You could replace it by `NExpectation` in the final integrand.  I threw in an extra `N` for just to be sure.  It takes so long to evaluate, I didn't have time to experiment.

```
AverageProbSuccess[B_, λ_] := Block[{n = 0, i, Expectation},
   i[r0_?NumericQ] := 
    Block[{r = r0}, 
     B*2*Gamma[λ*π + 1]/Gamma[λ*π]*
        r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ*π) /. 
       Expectation -> NExpectation // N];
   NIntegrate[i[r], {r, 0, Infinity},
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 1,
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[Mod[++n, 10] == 0, Print[n]]]
   ] // AbsoluteTiming

Print["Starting AverageProbSuccess"]

AverageProbSuccess[B, λ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not too surprising maybe, that it doesn't converge, since the following is so big:

```
Block[{r = 10.^12, Expectation = NExpectation},
 B*2*Gamma[λ*π + 1]/Gamma[λ*π]*
  r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ*π)
 ]
(*  5.5*10^9232413018186 + 1.42*10^9232413018186 I  *)

Block[{r = 10.^15, Expectation = NExpectation},
 B*2*Gamma[λ*π + 1]/Gamma[λ*π]*
  r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ*π)
 ]
```

> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

```
(*  Overflow[]  *)
```